# How to increment gimbal angle on android studio?

Tags: java, android, angle, dji-sdk

I have been working on this gimbal code for a while now trying to get my camera gimbal on my DJI Matrice 100 drone to slightly move every time you press the button direction. I tried using a for and while loop to increment the angle values but it seems to only read the angle inside the loop and not the loop itself. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get the gimbal to increment angles onClick?
This is the code for the gimbal rotation. (Note:The for loop line I was testing is commented out. Last tested the while loop.):

```
   private void rotateGimbalToMin (Button button) {

    DJIGimbal gimbal = getGimbalInstance();
    if (gimbal == null){
        return;
    }

    Object key = getCorrespondingKeyWithButton(button);
    Number minValue = ((DJIParamMinMaxCapability)(gimbal.gimbalCapability().get(key))).getMin();

    if (key == DJIGimbalCapabilityKey.AdjustPitch){ //down
        //for(double anglex = 0; anglex >= -180;anglex+= -20) {
        while(anglex != -180){
            mPitchRotation.direction = DJIGimbalRotateDirection.Clockwise;
            mPitchRotation.angle = -20; //TODO minValue.floatValue()
            anglex+= -20;
        }
    }

    if(key == DJIGimbalCapabilityKey.AdjustYaw){ //left
        //for(double anglex = 0; anglex <= 180; anglex+=20) {//test for loop
        while(anglex != 180){
            mYawRotation.direction = DJIGimbalRotateDirection.Clockwise;
            mYawRotation.angle = 20; //TODO minValue.floatValue()
            anglex+=20;
        }
    }

    sendRotateGimbalCommand();
}

private void rotateGimbalToMax(Button button) {

    DJIGimbal gimbal = getGimbalInstance();
    if (gimbal == null){
        return;
    }

    Object key = getCorrespondingKeyWithButton(button);
    Number maxValue = ((DJIParamMinMaxCapability)(gimbal.gimbalCapability().get(key))).getMax();

    if (key == DJIGimbalCapabilityKey.AdjustPitch){ //up
        //for(double anglex = 0; anglex <= 40; anglex+=20) {//test for loop
            while(anglex != 40){
            mPitchRotation.direction = DJIGimbalRotateDirection.Clockwise;
            mPitchRotation.angle = 10; //TODO maxValue.floatValue()
                this.anglex+=10;
        }
    }

    if(key == DJIGimbalCapabilityKey.AdjustYaw){ //right
        //for(double anglex = 0; anglex >= -180; anglex+=-20) {
        while(anglex != -180){
            mYawRotation.direction = DJIGimbalRotateDirection.Clockwise;
            mYawRotation.angle = -20; //TODO maxValue.floatValue()
            anglex+= -20;
        }
    }

//        if(key == DJIGimbalCapabilityKey.AdjustRoll){
//            mRollRotation.direction = DJIGimbalRotateDirection.Clockwise;
//            mRollRotation.angle = maxValue.floatValue();
//        }

    sendRotateGimbalCommand();
}
```

Below is the OnClick code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_capture:{
            captureAction();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn_shoot_photo_mode:{
            switchCameraMode(DJICameraSettingsDef.CameraMode.ShootPhoto);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn_record_video_mode:{
            switchCameraMode(DJICameraSettingsDef.CameraMode.RecordVideo);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn_goLeft:{
            rotateGimbalToMax((Button)v);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn_goRight:{
            rotateGimbalToMin((Button) v);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn_goDown:{
            rotateGimbalToMin((Button) v);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn_goUp:{
            rotateGimbalToMax((Button) v);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn_reset:{
            mPitchRotation.angle = 0;
            mYawRotation.angle = 0;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: (anglex) I can't find any reference to this.

Comment: Sorry the code has a lot of different things in it. But i have it listed globally in my code as double anglex=0;